# How do I do a where clause in sql and return a count back?

Tags: sql

I am using mssql and I want to make a query that returns a count back with a where clause.

Like say I have a product Table

```
ProductId
ProductName
Active
```

So how would I make it

I have like

```
Select Count(*)
From Product
```

now I don't know how to filter it so it only could if Active = true;

So if there are 3 active products then it would return a count of 3 even if there is a hundred rows in the db and the other 97 are only not active.

so the where clause would be probably like

```
where active = true
```

I am not sure how to put them together though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are there..just use:

```
Select Count(*)
From Product
where active = 'true'
```

Assuming your `active` field is of `varchar` or something similar.

Comment: Your where clause might have to be `where active = 1`, depending on the schema.

Comment: i bet you can use true as long as you don't quote it:
where active = true